# What is a difference between "sqlite" and "pysqlite2/sqlite3" modules?

Tags: python, sqlite, pysqlite

I gave up to make "sqlite3" working but I just found out (with help("modules")) that I have "sqlite" module. I tested it (create table, insert some values and so on) and it works fine. But before I start to use this module I would like to know if it has some significant limitations in comparison with sqlite3 module? Can anybody, pleas, give me advise?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [this wiki](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/PySqlite), you can ask your module exactly what version it is, e.g.:

```
>>> import sqlite
>>> sqlite.version
'1.0.1'
>>> sqlite._sqlite.sqlite_version()
'2.8.16'
```

So what versions numbers do you see when you try this?

A list of release note links from pysqlite version 2.3.4 to 2.5.5 (about 2 years' worth of releases) is available [here](http://oss.itsystementwicklung.de/trac/pysqlite/) -- so if you were using the 2.3.2 embedded in the sqlite3 that comes with Python 2.5 or the 2.4.1 that comes with Python 2.6 you could trace exactly what features, optimizations and bug fixes you might be missing (a long list). But 1.0.1 is SO far back that I don't know where to find a further list of changes from there to 2.3.2!  Looks like a job for an archeologist...;-).

I've seen a pysqlite tutorial [here](http://baijum81.livejournal.com/14159.html); full docs (LaTex sources) [here](http://oss.itsystementwicklung.de/trac/pysqlite/wiki/OldLatexDocs); good luck!

Comment: I get '1.1.7' and '3.3.6', respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I just install sqlite, and 'import sqlite3' works but not 'import sqlite'. You can use sqlite3.sqlite_version to find the package version. Thus

```
$ pip install sqlite==3.33.0
$ python
>>> import sqlite3
>>> sqlite3.version
'2.6.0'
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.33.0'
```